# Customizing classes won't work in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class

I'd like to create a wordpress blog about sports, so I created a CPT in the functions.php, and used wp_query to display it on my frontpage. So I created 3 fake articles with random titles, texts and images.

What I'd like to do is something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHBZC.jpg)

I created a custom CSS, and here's my front-page.php and css file

```
.item-article-front {
    background-color: black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

Above is the css, below is the php

<?php
        echo '<div class="row" >';
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'sport', 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php echo '<div class="entry-content col-md-4 item-article-front">'; ?>



                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

            <?php

            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
```

As you can see I tried to background-color the .item-article-front, but even though the class is actually attributed to the proper div, it won't display as I want. It's probably something stupid, but I can't find what that is. Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: someother CSS may be overwriting, use !important

Comment: It's probably an issue of [**CSS specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/); you've used a very 'low-value' selector. You'll need to post a screenshot of your F12 Developer Tools showcasing what rules are being applied to the element in question, along with their relevant selectors. Also, you should **never** need to use `!important`; you should instead work with specificity. `!important` does not fix bad CSS ;)

Comment: Yeah obviously I never use !important unless I try to fix a bug, but I get rid of that ASAP ! I tried to copy the selector in the dev tab, it doesn't work, and it seems like the css is not even recognized ( though the link is good between the HTML/CSS since I did my navbar with a custom CSS. ). Here's a screen of the dev tab http://prntscr.com/incw1z
Thanks !